# Build an empty MVC DropdownListFor for a Cascade Sub-List

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, html.dropdownlistfor

I would like to build an empty Dropdownlistfor to received the results of a previous Dropdownlisfor selection:

The actual view:

```
    <div id="makes">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Make_Id, Model.MakeList, HeelpResources.DropdownlistMakeFirstRecord)
    </div>
    <div id="models">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Model_Id, Model.ModelList, HeelpResources.DropdownlistModelFirstRecord)
    </div>
```

The actual Controller (to work I had to build an empty SelectedList but it seems strange to have to do this):

```
   public virtual ActionResult Create()
    {
        // Build the Dropdownlist for the Makes
        var makesDto = _makeService.ListAllMakes();
        var makesViewModel = Mapper.Map<IList<MakeDto>, IList<MakeViewModel>>(makesDto);

        // Build the Dropdownlist for the Models
        var makeId = -1;
        var modelsDto = _modelService.ListModelByMake(makeId);
        var modelsViewModel = Mapper.Map<IList<ModelDto>, IList<ModelViewModel>>(modelsDto);

        // Build the ViewModel to return to the View
        CreateAdViewModel viewModel = new CreateAdViewModel();
        viewModel.MakeList = new SelectList(makesViewModel, "ID", "Name");
        viewModel.ModelList = new SelectList(modelsViewModel, "ID", "Name"); 

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Is there a way to build something like this: 
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Model_Id, null)

And remove the // Build the Dropdownlist for the Models from the controller?

Thanks

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Found a solution that I think is the best because it as no service call to build the dropdroplist empty and it's strongly typed:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Model_Id, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), HeelpResources.DropdownlistModelFirstRecord)
```

Comment: It would be good if you marked this as the answer to your own question.

Comment: what is the use of "HeelpResources.DropdownlistModelFirstRecord"?

Comment: It's the text that you want to put in the first option like "Please Select an option...", but based in a Resource String so you can present this text based in the location's language website (French/Portuguese/English)

Answer (score 2):

**The following is working**:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Model_Id, **new SelectList(new List<string>()**));
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would do this with a bit of jQuery and an additional partial view. Your form could look like this:

```
<div id="makes">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Make_Id, Model.MakeList, HeelpResources.DropdownlistMakeFirstRecord)
</div>
<div id="models">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
   $("#Make_Id").change(function(){
       $("#models").load("/Controller_Name/GetModels/" + this.val());
   }
});
</script>
```

and then in your controller:

```
public ActionResult GetModels(int id)
{
   ViewBag.DdlModels = new SelectList(rep.GetModelsForCar(id), "Id", "Name");
   return PartialView();
}
```

and then just stick your drop down list in the GetModels partial view

Comment: And the Model dropdown gets strongly typed in the view coming the partial view? It will pass the Model_Id selected value from the dropdown to the controller inside the viewmodel?