# How to create an empty dropdown list with default value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I want to create an empty dropdown list that has just default value.I use the following code:

```
@Html.DropDownList("parent","--Select Parent--")
```

But in running time I see this error:

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that
>   has the key 'parent'.

How can I solve it?
Thanks.

Comment: Try this `@Html.DropDownList(null, "--Select Parent--")`.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud : And now the error is changed to this:Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: name

Comment: OK, then that won't work. You'll need to follow @Shyju direction. The issue is it's trying to bind to a property named "parent".

Comment: you can simply create an HTML select option. but the question is still alive, why you want to create an empty dropdown? the good way is to create one page for NEW and EDIT and use a ViewModel to generate data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may simply create an HTML Select option in your view.

```
<select id="parent" name="parent">
   <option value="">Select parent </option>
</select>
```

**EDIT :** *As per the comment*.

When you submit the form, You can get the selected value by either having a parameter with `parent` name

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(string parent,string otherParameterName)
{
  //read and save and return / redirect
}
```

**OR** have a `parent` property in your ViewModel which you are using for Model binding.

```
public class CreateProject
{
  public string parent { set;get;}
  public string ProjectName { set;get;}
}
```

and in your action method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateProject model)
{

  // check model.parent value.
}
```

Comment: But this kind of HTML objects would not be submited in the forms like this:
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{}

Comment: ofcourse it will. Whatever Helper method you use (ex : Html.DropDownListFor) will also generate HTML markup like this only. In your `HttpPost` action, you can use a `parent` parameter or have a `parent` property in your viewmodel.

Comment: Just the name of my dropdown list should be the same with the property in my view model.there is no need to get it in my controller.In the controller I just need to get a variable with type of view model.Art of MVC...

Answer (score 24):

You can build an empty DropDownList like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("parent", Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "--Select Parent--")
```

Reference: [Build an empty MVC DropdownListFor for a Cascade Sub-List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13051228/build-an-empty-mvc-dropdownlistfor-for-a-cascade-sub-list)

Comment: Thank You your partially helped me to return empty dropdown  .. 
My Code :
IW.SelItemList = new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>());

Answer (score 8):

Adding html attributes to the above example:

```
    @Html.DropDownList("Idparent", Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "Select one...", new {@class="form-control"})
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in your controller to build a empty dropdown list

```
    ViewBag.ClassID = new SelectList(db.Classes.Where(c => c.ClassID == 0)  , "ClassID", "ClassName").ToList();
```